# Unsupported instrument/aggregator combo, types ValueRecorder and MinMaxSumCountAggregator, ignoring it

Tags: python, open-telemetry

Trying to adjust the following example: https://google-cloud-opentelemetry.readthedocs.io/en/latest/examples/cloud_monitoring/README.html to use a value recorder instead.

```py
        metrics.set_meter_provider(MeterProvider())
        meter = metrics.get_meter(__name__)
        metrics.get_meter_provider().start_pipeline(
            meter, CloudMonitoringMetricsExporter(), 5
        )

        ratio_metric = meter.create_valuerecorder(
            name="ratio_values",
            description="Ratio for a given tool",
            unit="ratio",
            value_type=float,
        )

        ratio_values_a = {"symbol": "testA"}
        ratio_values_b = {"symbol": "testB"}
        ratio = 1.000

        for i in range(20):
            if i > 10:
                ratio_metric.record(0.999, ratio_values_a)
                ratio_metric.record(ratio, ratio_values_b)
                ratio -= 0.1
            else:
                ratio_metric.record(0.999, ratio_values_a)
                ratio_metric.record(ratio, ratio_values_b)
                ratio += 0.2
            time.sleep(10)
```

Gives the following error:

```
Unsupported instrument/aggregator combo, types ValueRecorder and MinMaxSumCountAggregator, ignoring it
Unsupported instrument/aggregator combo, types ValueRecorder and MinMaxSumCountAggregator, ignoring it
```

With the following versions running:

```
opentelemetry-api==1.10a0
opentelemetry-exporter-gcp-monitoring==1.2.0a0
opentelemetry-sdk==1.10a0
```

Comment: Were you able to find a workaround or a solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was an issue with very old packages and will not addressed. A lot of concepts when these packages were written based on specification no longer exists. There is a work in progress new SDK implementation which is ready for experimental use you may want to check https://github.com/open-telemetry/opentelemetry-python/tree/main/docs/examples/metrics